# Are there any sources on the Tempestarii?

Tags: france, early-medieval, franks, norse-mythology, celtic

The Tempestarii were weather mages in the Frankish Empire Recorded and were recorded on by Agobard of Lyons. I read the text he wrote on them but I cannot find other texts on them that go into more detail. I am also having trouble figuring out their origin whether it was Germanic or Gaulish because of their similarly in weather mythology. Does anyone know information on their origin and practices? The main text I have gone through is Agobard of Lyons on Hail and Thunder along with the Wiki page and other folktales on weather sorcery such as the Solomonari.

Comment: Hello and welcome to History.SE. [Wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tempestarii) on them implies that tempestarii was a fancy Latin catch-all name for village witches who claimed to be able to affect weather (not an organized group). It also points out that Agobard's work is basically a rant on how they all are charlatans and how his parishioners are superstitious fools for believing in them (his main argument - only God, saints and angels can change weather, not heathen magic). Do you have any sources that led you to believe that was not the case?

Comment: @DanilaSmirnov I understand that Agobard denouces them as charalatans, and it was a catch all term, but even catch all terms still have practices and origins associated with them. So I was just inquiring on more information on the origin and practices of these people.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace Are you asking if you should provide sources in your answer or are you asking for sources from me in my question?

Comment: @Amoeba Mark is asking you to describe the research you already did so that others will not duplicate.  You state "cannot find other texts"... but where did you look?  Also he is asking you for your sources... can you link to Agobard's work or the wiki on him so that every other person who attempts to help will not also have to search the same down.  This should be edited into question as comments are ephemeral.